# Where can I find a Node.js error code lookup table and meaning

Tags: node.js, unix, npm

I'm trying to debug my stack trace from npm installs that go wrong and I'm getting all these great error codes. It would be useful except I have NO idea what any of these codes means. And I've googled frantically for a node.js error code look up table. I don't want to run a stupid error code program to find the code I'm looking for and it's meaning, I just want a normal table or a link to some documentation on what that code means.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you won't find such a table is that these codes are usually bubbled up from an underlying system.  Node.js is an amalgam of a lot of things, and they all have their own errors.

Google the specific error you get, and you'll find your answer.